# Passing html input value to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am uploading images using ajax. Since I have a `table` that lists the records, there are more than one rows and I can't add images except first row's ID. I probably have to give my function a parameter, but I couldn't figure out how to implement it to the ajax part.

What I want to do is to POST `thing_id` value to my php form while uploading images.

I **updated** the question, see details.

Here's how I activate my modal.

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#image-edit<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>"><span
class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

My modal (You wanted more details, so I am posting the whole modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="image-edit<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                      aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>">Add Photos</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- image upload area start-->
                <div class="addabook">
                    <div class="new-entry-main">
                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="myform">
                            <div class="bookcoverdiv">
                                <p>Book Cover</p>
                                <input type="file" name="images[]" id="<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>" multiple>
                                <input type="hidden" id="secret<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>" name="thing_id" value="<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>">
                                <button type="button" onclick="imageupload(<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>)" value="<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>" class="uploadimages btn btn-primary">Save changes
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="content_here_please"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php // I list previously uploaded images here. They appear, so my modal works. ?>
            </div>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
        function imageupload(thing_id) {
        var form = new FormData($('.myform')[0]);
        form.append('thing_id', thing_id);
        // Make the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadimages.php',
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function () {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progress, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            //add beforesend handler to validate or something
            //beforeSend: functionname,
            success: function (res) {
                $('.content_here_please').html(res);
            },
            //add error handler for when a error occurs if you want!
            //error: errorfunction,
            data: form,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    }
```

PHP

```
$get_id = $_POST['thing_id'];
echo $get_id; // it echoes the id number of the record when I click the anchor, but there is something weird. I list 10 records each page. If I try to make a change on the 2nd or 3rd record, all modals show $get_id value.
```

Proof : [image: http://i.imgur.com/gz2Wf60.png]

Answer (score 1):

You can append the data you pass to `imageupload` to the FormData object like below. (using the original button click code)

```
function imageupload(thing_id) {
    var form = new FormData($('.myform')[0]);
    form.append('thing_id', thing_id);
    ...
```

Comment: I already have one, could you please check EDIT 2? I changed my question a little bit.

Comment: Do you use `$_POST['thing_id']` to access the value?

Comment: Yes, of course I do. The PHP part works, but I can only upload images to the first row (I think it just selects the first row when you didn't specify using ajax)

Comment: I use bootstrap, there are almost 300 lines of code. I added more detail to edit #2, please check it out.

Comment: So there are multiple buttons in the form with different ids?

Comment: Yes, exactly..... I click the photo icon and a modal opens, then I upload images in there. Just to give you an idea : http://i.imgur.com/zPddvHr.png

Comment: since you're unable to resolve your issue, you could create a JS fiddle that demonstrates your issue. Just a small piece of code that reproduces the problem, not whole code.

Comment: @Ejay I updated question details and tried to make it as clear as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to insert a hidden field on your form containing the ID that you want.

For instance,

```
<form id="myForm">
...other fields
   <input type="hidden" name="thing_id" value="<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>">
</form>
```

And then on server side, you can access the variable with the ID 'thing_id' because you're sending the form to the server on your AJAX call.

Answer (score -2):

Use data attribute in the ajax to pass data to php page and in php page you can passed data $_GET['name'] , Check below example

```
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Add extra variable in your function like that

```
function imageupload() {

var form = new FormData($('.myform')[0]);
var thing_id = "<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>";

// Make the ajax call
$.ajax({
```

And then use in ajax

```
 // Make the ajax call
$.ajax({
    url: 'uploadimages.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {thing_id:thing_id }, //first thing_id will go to php as $_POST['thing_id']; the second one is thing_id from the code above
    xhr: function () {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
```